# Maven project appearing as path

Tags: eclipse, git

I have 3 `Maven` projects, but the 3th is appearing like a path in `Eclipse`. How do I set to `Eclipse` understand that Project 3 is a `Maven` Project, not a path?

[image]

**EDIT**: This occurred after I switch for other branch at GitLab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by clicking on `Project3` with the right button of the mouse, click on **Import**, select **Existing Maven Projects**, **select my project** and **Finish**.

**EDIT**: you can also select **Import as project**